# OOP is discouraged in Rust but there don't seem to be a lot of alternatives for it in 3d applications

Tags: oop, rust, 3d

I am trying to write a 3d application in rust and since I don't know any suitable alternatives I am currently "approximating" some java like classes using enums.

What I have looks something like this:

```
enum SceneObj {
    Plane(Plane),
    Sphere(Sphere),
}
```

Where `Plane` and `Sphere` are both structs. The this is necessary since I want to sore a vec of scene objects.

The problem now arises when I try to, for example, get the position of one of these scene objects. I always have to do something like this:

```
fn get_scobj_pos(obj: SceneObj) -> Vector {
    match obj {
        SceneObj::Plane(p) => { p.get_pos() }
        SceneObj::Sphere(s) => { s.get_pos() }
    }
}
```

This is really annoying and gets very verbose quickly. It also seems very redundant since all scene objects implement the same trait with these functions.

If I was using a language like Java, C# etc. I could just make the parent class Object and have Plane and Sphere inherit from it.

My question essentially boils down to: is there an alternative solution other than enums. More esoteric alternatives to OOP in 3d programming are also very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to create a `trait SceneObj`, then use `Box<dyn SceneObj>` if you plan on owning and storing the objects.

Traits are similar to interfaces in Java.

```rust
trait SceneObj {
    fn get_pos(&self) -> &Vector;
}

struct Plane {
    pos: Vector
}

impl SceneObj for Plane {      //~        class Plane implements SceneObj
    fn get_pos(&self) -> &Vector {  //~   @Override Vector getPos()
        &self.pos
    }
}
```

But you should avoid using `Box<dyn Trait>` carelessly.

Answer (score 3):

Prefer composition over inheritance, then use helper traits to access different parts of your composed objects more easily. In your case you could do something like:

```
struct Vector {}

struct BaseObject {
    pos: Vector,
}

trait AsBaseObject {
    fn as_base_object (&self) -> &BaseObject;
    fn get_pos (&self) -> &Vector {
        &self.as_base_object().pos
    }
}

impl AsBaseObject for BaseObject {
    fn as_base_object (&self) -> &BaseObject { self }
}

struct Plane {
    base: BaseObject,
}

impl AsBaseObject for Plane {
    fn as_base_object (&self) -> &BaseObject {
        &self.base
    }
}

struct Sphere {
    base: BaseObject,
}

impl AsBaseObject for Sphere {
    fn as_base_object (&self) -> &BaseObject {
        &self.base
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=63025038d867d67090883a2a5ee946f0)

Comment: That's a really interesting approach I will definitely look into more, right now @ImajinDevon 's solution was a bit easier to use in my existing codebase

Comment: That's right, but you don't need to define your own trait for that, `AsRef<BaseObject>` does exactly the same thing as `AsBaseObject` with the added benefit of being known to Rust programmers already.