# Multiple inheritance for OOP-like Rust

Tags: oop, rust, multiple-inheritance

I want to implement an OOP approach in Rust. My base class `BaseClass` would look like this (but with more parameters):

```rust
struct BaseClass {
    name: String,
}

impl BaseClass {
    fn new(name: &str) -> Self {
        Self{name: name.to_string()}
    }
}
```

This base class has an associated trait that does the trick for inheritance:

```rust
trait BaseClassInterface {
    fn as_base(&self) -> &BaseClass;
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str {
        &self.as_base().name
    }
}
```

Now, I want to inherit from this base class and add extra stuff with generics:

```rust
struct MiddleClass<T> {
    base: BaseClass,
    value: T,
}

impl<T> MiddleClass<T> {
    fn new(name: &str, value: T) -> Self {
        Self{base: BaseClass::new(name), value}
    }
}
```

Again, this is an "abstract" class. Users of my library will "inherit" from this middle class to define their structs. So let's do a trait for it:

```rust
trait MiddleClassInterface {
    type Type;
    fn as_middle(&self) -> &MiddleClass<Self::Type>;
    fn get_value(&self) -> &Self::Type {
        &self.as_middle().value
    }
}
```

Now we implement the `BaseClassInterface` trait for the `MiddleClassInterface` trait and we achieved "class inheritance"!

```rust
impl<T> BaseClassInterface for dyn MiddleClassInterface<Type = T> {
    fn as_base(&self) -> &BaseClass {
        &self.as_middle().base
    }
}
```

So now, users can implement their own versions of the `MiddleClassInterface` and use methods from the `BaseClassInterface` trait:

```rust
struct MyIntClass {
    middle: MiddleClass<i32>,
}

impl MyIntClass {
    fn new(name: &str, value: i32) -> Self {
        Self{middle: MiddleClass::new(name, value)}
    }
}

impl MiddleClassInterface for MyIntClass {
    type Type = i32;
    fn as_middle(&self) -> &MiddleClass<Self::Type> {
        &self.middle
    }
}
```

As `MyIntClass` implements the `MiddleClassInterface`, `MyIntClass` will implement the `BaseClassInterface`... or not?
Let's look at my `main` function:

```rust
fn main() {
    let my_class = MyIntClass::new("my_class", 1);
    println!("{}", my_class.get_name());
}
```

When compiling, I get the following error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `get_name` found for struct `MyIntClass` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:71:29
   |
52 | struct MyIntClass {
   | ----------------- method `get_name` not found for this
...
71 |     println!("{}", my_class.get_name());
   |                             ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `MyIntClass`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
note: `BaseClassInterface` defines an item `get_name`, perhaps you need to implement it
  --> src/main.rs:13:1
   |
13 | trait BaseClassInterface {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
```

`MyIntClass` implements the `MiddleClassInterface<i32>` class, which in turn implements the `BaseClassInterface` trait. So... why does `MyIntClass` not implement the `BaseClassInterface` indirectly?

Thanks in advance!

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3aa8007b440b965aedf124a69dacc6f7

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73163713/5397009

Comment: I think forcing OOP patterns onto Rust goes kind of against the whole point of it. In my opinion at least. The patterns that emerge from Rusts trait model are really clean, so I'd advise reading into alternatives to OOP instead.

Comment: I see, thanks for your feedback. I'm still very new to Rust and I tend to use OOP because it is what I am used to. I'll read for alternatives and see if I can think of other way to implement my stuff.

Comment: What you're doing here is closer to composition than inheritance, and composition usually winds up being cleaner anyway.

Comment: So, I guess that in composition, the AsMiddle trait would coerce the AsBase trait instead of implementing it indirectly, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will work if you change:

```
impl<T> BaseClassInterface for dyn MiddleClassInterface<Type = T> {
```

to:

```
impl<T> BaseClassInterface for T where T: MiddleClassInterface {
```

What you did above is implement `BaseClassInterface` for a *trait object* but such implementations are not considered for method lookup on concrete types. You would first have to *coerce* `my_class` into a trait for it to work:

```
(&my_class as &dyn MiddleClassInterface<Type=i32>).get_name())
```

Whereas the fix is to not implement `BaseClassInterface` for a trait object, but rather implement it for all types that implement the `MiddleClassInterface`. The difference being that `MyIntClass` will itself implement the base class and won't have to go through dynamic dispatch to call those methods.

Comment: I see, I have to avoid dynamic programming as much as I can. Thanks for your response!