# Two level inheritance in Rust

Tags: inheritance, rust, struct, traits

I have a double level of (say inheritance, I am not sure about the exact name in Rust).

```
           Question
     _________|_________
     |                 |
 Operation         Equation
              _________|_________
              |                 |
          OneVariable     TwoVariables
```

Well, my understanding is that a branch should be a trait and a leaf should be a struct. Neither a struct can be inherited nor a trait can have values.
I reduced the code to the following:

```
pub trait Question {
    fn new(whatever) -> Self;
}

pub struct Operation{--snip--}

impl Question for Operation {
    fn new(whatever) -> Operation {--snip--}
}

pub trait Equation: Question,
{
    fn new(whatever) -> Self; //Bookmark1
}


pub struct OneVariable {--snip--}

impl Question for OneVariable {--snip--} //Bookmark2
impl Equation for OneVariable {--snip--} //Bookmark3
```

(And the same for `TwoVariables`).

**Question**:
Where shall I implement `new()` for the `OneVariable`?

Comment: Why not in `impl OneVariable { … }`?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/73163713/5397009

Comment: Because, OneVariable is a Child of Equation and a grand child of Question, and it needs to inherit its methods. That's why they created traits I believe.

Comment: So? You already have `impl Question for OneVariable` and `impl Equation for OneVariable`, which give you access to the ancestor methods. Simply add `impl OneVariable { … }` for the methods that don't come from any of the traits.

Comment: Just fyi, `trait Equation: Question { ... }` is a little more idiomatic than `trait Equation where Self: Question { ... }`.

Comment: @isaactfa, thanks for the info. Actually I put it like you said, but rust analyzer suggested this :)

Comment: @Jaafar Oh, interesting. Never mind me then :) I'll have to try and reproduce that.

Comment: @Jmb, I think the question is clear, I am asking about the new() function which is coming from the trait Question.

Comment: I hadn't seen that you had functions named `new` in your traits. The one from the trait `Question` should go into `impl Question for OneVariable` and the one from the trait `Equation` should go into `impl Equation for OneVariable`. They are different functions which should _both_ be implemented.

Comment: "Child" "Grandchild" "inherit" - that's not really the purpose of traits, from my understanding. I can't but wonder if there's a better way to solve what you are trying to achieve withough utilizing OOP patterns. OOP patterns don't really go with the Rust programming language in my experience. There are a lot of alternatives that work much better, but it's hard to say without knowing the underlying problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: For example, it's very suspicious to me that all your traits have a `new()` method. It's very unusual in my experience for a trait to have a `new()` method. Traits can't be created, traits don't carry data, they are purely interface definitions. The structs that implement the traits should have new() methods.

Comment: Thanks @isaactfa, as for the idiomatic representation we discussed in comments, I reviewed it, Rust Analyzer was not suggesting it, but rather, once you hover on Equation, it shows:
pub trait Equation
where
    Self: Question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jmb points out, if `OneVariable` is supposed to be *both* a `Question` *and* an `Equation`, it'll have to implement both of those traits' methods:

```
pub trait Question {
    fn new() -> Self;
}

pub trait Equation: Question {
    fn new() -> Self;
}

pub struct Operation {}

impl Question for Operation {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }
}

pub struct OneVariable {}

impl Question for OneVariable {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }
}

impl Equation for OneVariable {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }
}
```

One trick you can do is to provide a default implementation of `new` in the supertrait based on the base trait:

```
pub trait Equation: Question {
    fn new() -> Self
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        <Self as Question>::new()
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // use the `new` method we already have by default
    }
}
```

This does however require the bound `Self: Sized` on `Equation`'s `new` method and, of course, only makes sense if the signatures of both `new` methods are compatible.

Comment: Note that `Self: Sized` is implicit and does not need to be added to the `where` clause.

Comment: @Jmb Actually, in traits `Self` isn't bound by `Sized` automatically like it is everywhere else. You usually don't notice because most trait methods take or return `self` by reference so it doesn't matter whether it's `Sized` or not.

Comment: Oh, right, my bad

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but I think you will become very frustrated if you keep holding on to OOP patterns in Rust. Rust is not meant to be used as an OOP language, and most patterns are only possible to be implemented with a lot of pain or not at all.

The words "parent", "grandparent", "inherit" simply don't apply to Rust and traits. The words are rather "interface definition", "implementation", "abstraction". For example, traits cannot carry data. Every pattern in OOP that assumes that parents are autonomous beings or have any functionality, for that matter, simply does not work in Rust. Yes, traits can have default implementations, but those default implementations can only call other trait functions. They cannot modify any internal data, because, as said, traits do not carry any data.

I've seen that you use `new()` a lot in your traits. That's something typical in OOP, where to construct a class, you have to call the parent constructor. You **can not** construct a trait, and you can **not** call a 'parent' constructor in Rust, because those things simply do not exist. There is no point in having a `new()` function in a trait.

You simply create an object of a struct, and then the traits it implements specify how that object can be used.

You can implement traits based on other traits, of course, but that requires a rethinking of how your functionality is layed out.

That said, there are great alternative patterns. But that depends heavily on your usecase, of course.

From what you showed so far, my first instinct is to lay out the trait/struct pattern like this (although this is of course just a feeling, as I don't know what exact usecase you have):

```
pub trait Question {
    fn do_question_thing(&self);
}

pub trait Equation {
    fn do_equation_thing(&self);
}

pub struct OneVariable {
    data: String,
}

impl OneVariable {
    pub fn new(s: &str) -> Self {
        Self {
            data: s.to_string(),
        }
    }
}

// Make `OneVariable` an `Equation`
impl Equation for OneVariable {
    fn do_equation_thing(&self) {
        println!("Doing equation thing: {:?}", self.data);
    }
}

// Make all `Equation`s be `Question`s
impl<T> Question for T
where
    T: Equation,
{
    fn do_question_thing(&self) {
        println!("Doing a question thing, which triggers:");
        self.do_equation_thing();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let one_variable = OneVariable::new("Hello world!");
    one_variable.do_question_thing();
}
```

```
Doing a question thing, which triggers:
Doing equation thing: "Hello world!"
```

As you can see, it's somewhat defined in reverse compared to OOP. You say "OneThing is an Equation", and then define all the functionality that an Equation has to fullfill. Then, you say "All Equations are Questions" and implement the functionality that Questions need to provide based on the functionality of Equations. OOP would be kind of the other way round.

Then, if you instantiate a `OneVariable`, it automatically has all the functionality of a `Question` implemented, if it implements `Equation`.

This isn't better or worse than OOP, it's just different. You can't do a couple of things with this that you could do with OOP, like `abstract` and `overwrite`, but it has big advantages in other places, like pure trait crates for clean abstraction layers between libraries (for example the [`log`](https://docs.rs/log) crate; if you use it for logging, you can simply swap the log backends as they all implement the same logging traits).

Comment: "for example the log crate; if you use it for logging, you can simply swap the log backends as they all implement the same logging traits" - why couldn't you do this with OOP as well? Just have a `Logger` base class and create an instance of different subclass? Most OOP languages even support `interface` now, why not use that together with inheritance? Genuinely looking to hear your thoughts as someone who's looking to pick up Rust but hesitating due to lack of inheritance.

Comment: Trust me, the lack of inheritance is **not** a blocker. I've worked with Rust for a while now, and the trait system is excellent. It requires a little bit of rethinking, but it has huge advantages. For example that you can implement new functionality for foreign types. Everybody can simply add new functionality to for example `std` types, as is being done in the [`itertools`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/) crate. It might take some time to rethink, but then you will get to love it.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Inheritance has its big downsides, which is why most game engines don't use it any more. They use entity-component systems instead. A game I worked on made the switch from inheritance to entity-component-system at some point and the main dev wrote a [blog article](https://www.moddb.com/members/koonschi/blogs/making-avorions-game-model-an-entity-component-model) about it, in case you are curious.

Comment: Being able to inject new functionality for foreign types sounds horrible to me! JavaScript has prototypes and nothing sucks more than multiple libraries injecting into `Array.prototype` and having collisions with their implementations to the point where they're unusable together. The OOP solution would be to inherit `MyLibraryArray extends Array` and now anyone can use which ever they prefer!

Games prefer ECS for performance. Referring to your blog, I'd argue that in an ideal world every `BlockObject` *should* be ownable, it's the performance that's limiting us. Also ECS is awesome.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how traits work here. The orphaning rules prevent exactly the problems that javascript has. You can freely inject things that collide, nothing bad will happen. You can't actually "inject" into anything, you can simply implement a new trait. A trait can have the same function names as the original object, and you can switch between then based on the context. To be honest, I work with Rust on all of my private projects and with C/C++/Python at work, and it's painful to go back to OOP once you are used to the power of traits.

Comment: There is no point in arguing, you won't believe me no matter what I say, that's the problem with OOP devs I've found in the past. What you have to do is try it out yourself, and be prepared to deal with the culture shock of having to re-learn different patterns. It really is a culture shock for OOP programmers, because due to the limits of OOP a lot of bad patterns emerged that Rust doesn't allow and programmers have to un-learn and re-learn. If you can't deal with this, learning Rust might be hard for you. But if you manage to power through, you will love it.

Comment: I sometimes feel like learning Rust is easier for new programmers than for professional OOP programmers :/ It was painful for me at the beginning. Especially the ownership part. But now that I'm used to it, I don't wanna do anything else any more. Rust gives you so many compile time stability guarantees that I feel this inner rage when I program with other languages. I actually realized how many bad habits I had, and started to apply better patterns to C/C++, being frustrated if the language forced me back to bad habits.

Comment: I think you drew some conclusions there, I *am* currently trying out Rust and trying to learn new patterns, but I just keep running into code duplication issues everywhere (e.g. having to implement the same trait mostly the same way for different structs). Rust's ownership is something you should have been doing in C++ & Python all these years already, I like that it's built-in to the language and it's the main reason I'm trying to adapt Rust. It's just the lack of inheritance that keeps pushing me away, I don't want to do ECS or functional everywhere, sometimes OOP *is* the best solution.

Comment: I also don't think you're being fair towards "OOP devs", a good dev knows that different tools and patterns should be used to solve different problems. I'm not saying "use inheritance always everywhere", I'm saying "every now and then inheritance would be the best solution", and my hatred towards Rust is growing since they refuse to accept that multiple paradigms are viable.

Comment: Fair :) Didn't mean to be rude. Sorry. I think this is a very healthy mindset :) I think Rust people are a little on the edge about that topic **because** they have made bad experiences in these kind of discussions. I agree that in some situations it might be the best solution, but so far I've always found an alternative way. There is one situation where I have to agree with you though - it makes implementing GUI frameworks a lot harder. In most other situations though, it turned out to be the cleaner way to avoid OOP.

Comment: *"refuse to accept that multiple paradigms are viable"* - well, that's not true :) most of us are also multi-language programmers, I for example have many years of C++ and Python experience. It's just that Rust doesn't have those, and so far it still worked out well in all the situations we tried to use it, so we refuse to let that stop us from loving it :) We can't change the fact that Rust is not OOP, and with its current premises it's now impossible to make it OOP. That would make it a worse language, because some other invariants of the language would have to be broken.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254197/discussion-between-finomnis-and-markus-meskanen).