# Use shared (not default) implementation for traits

Tags: rust

I'm trying to understand how traits and generics work.
I have two structures that would do exactly the same operations on some of their fields. How would I implement trait for them without creating code duplication?

```rust
trait MyTrait {
    fn do_something(&mut self);
}

struct A {
    field1: i32,
    field2: i32,
    // .. data for struct A ..
}

struct B {
    field1: i32,
    field2: i32,
    // .. data for struct B ..
}

impl MyTrait for A {
    fn do_something(&mut self) {
        // lots of same code
        self.field1 = self.field1 + 1;
        self.field2 = self.field2 + 2;
    }
}

impl MyTrait for B {
    fn do_something(&mut self) {
        // lots of same code
        self.field1 = self.field1 + 1;
        self.field2 = self.field2 + 2;
    }
}
```

One way I think is too use generic, but I can't figure out how to tell it to use types of struct A or B:

```rust
trait MyTrait {
    fn do_something(&mut self);
}

struct A {
    field1: i32,
    field2: i32,
    // .. data for struct A ..
}

struct B {
    field1: i32,
    field2: i32,
    // .. data for struct B ..
}


fn shared_do_something<T: MyTrait>(t: &mut T)
{
    // shared implementation
    t.field1 += 1;  // error no field `field1` on type `&mut T`
    t.field2 += 2;  // error no field `field2` on type `&mut T`
}

impl MyTrait for A {
    fn do_something(&mut self) {
        shared_do_something(self);
    }
}

impl MyTrait for B {
    fn do_something(&mut self) {
        shared_do_something(self);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first code snippet might be suitable, it depends on the use-case I guess. Why it is not enough for your case?

Comment: @BiagioF: The first code snippet is the one with code duplication. The OP is asking for a way to avoid duplication. It's a legitimate thing to want, especially when the code gets more complex, and/or when the duplicated code should *always* be the same for both structs, with all changes applied to both simultaneously.

Comment: Food for thought: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73163713/5397009

Comment: I feel there should be some way to tell compiler to use one of the types like it's done for traits, `where T: A or B` or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three options:

- Use a macro

  ```
  macro_rules! my_trait_impl {
      ($t:ty) => {
          impl MyTrait for $t {
              fn do_something(&mut self) {
                  self.field1 = self.field1 + 1;
                  self.field2 = self.field2 + 2;
              }
          }
      };
  }
  my_trait_impl!(A);
  my_trait_impl!(B);
  ```

  [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2dfb8aba1170fca90115bf07be390468)
- Use a "view struct" that gives mutable access to the common fields

  ```
  struct F1F2View<'a> {
      field1: &'a mut i32,
      field2: &'a mut i32,
  }

  fn shared_do_something(t: F1F2View) {
      *t.field1 += 1;
      *t.field2 += 2;
  }

  impl MyTrait for A {
     fn do_something(&mut self) {
          shared_do_something(F1F2View {
              field1: &mut self.field1,
              field2: &mut self.field2,
          });
      }
  }
  ```

  [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6c21a5be969394eb9ef7ba54dbfcf8f7)
- Trait methods that give access to the fields (with a default implementation as a tickle of fancy) - doesn't necessarily have to be the same trait:

  ```
  trait MyTrait {
      fn field1_mut(&mut self) -> &mut i32;
      fn field2_mut(&mut self) -> &mut i32;

      fn do_something(&mut self) {
          *self.field1_mut() += 1;
          *self.field2_mut() += 2;
      }
  }
  impl MyTrait for A {
      fn field1_mut(&mut self) -> &mut i32 { &mut self.field1 }
      fn field2_mut(&mut self) -> &mut i32 { &mut self.field2 }
  }
  ```

  [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=311dfbce71dbeffb34dbb3747ada831e)

The first example can become gnarly if the implementation of  `MyTrait` is complex.
For the second example, it may be worthwhile to define a different trait that produces the view struct. This trait can then be implemented in a macro.

Comment: Well, these solutions do work... they are ugly though. Maybe in the future Rust developers would solve that. And after reading Rust Koans I think I can live with some code duplication :) https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rust-koans/2408/4

Comment: There isn't anything to solve. Different structs are different structs, and you won't be able to access their fields from a single function, even if some of the field names overlap. Oh, and I forgot one option: Put common fields into a common substruct: `struct A { common: Common, /* ... */ } struct Common { field1: i32, field2: i32 }`