State for Trait Implementation in Rust
I'm trying to learn Rust, and the choices behind having traits be implemented separately makes no sense to me. Ostensibly, this is helpful because it allows you to add behavior to a type you don't own. But there's no statefulness!
For example, imagine I have a struct Water in some crate which I do not own. And I want to implement behavior for my trait Matter to embody the behavior of states of matter.
crate1
struct Water {
    num_moles: u128,
    // suppose there's some stuff here about molecular structure
    ...
}

crate2
trait Matter {
    fn temperature(&self) -> i32;
    fn melt(&mut self);
    fn freeze(&mut self);
    fn evaporate(&mut self);
    fn condense(&mut self);
    fn get_matter_state(&self) -> str;
}

Now, I'd like to implement this to make Water a type of Matter, but I need both state and constant variables to do this. But in an impl Matter for Water block, I can't do this. Yet, I can't edit the Water struct either, since I do not own the code. How can I store the current temperature, then?

Nitpick: -> () is redundant.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73163713/5397009

State & trait inheritance w/ decorator pattern variant
This answer addresses a more general question for how state and traits can be associated in a hierarchical relationship.
Relevant to the OP question, the decorator pattern could be applied to objects from external crates that have features one finds useful, but want to extend. One could create their own Water struct that has a field holding the other crate's Water and leverage its methods in its own impl.
The rest of this approach doesn't deal specifically with how to apply the decorator pattern to items from other crates. It deals more generally with how to apply the decorator pattern and leverage the features of the language to achieve an object hierarchy.
You can achieve statefulness in a hierarchy of object types through a combination of traits and structs. This does have quite a bit of overhead; partitioning a large project into a file for each type can help manage it.
Below loosely applies the basic idea of the Decorator Pattern to achieve Object Oriented design goals where "subclasses" inherit behaviors and also state indirectly.
The idea is to have a struct closely related to a trait. The trait defines an unimplemented method that returns a reference to its related state struct, which is implemented by "subclasses".
In the trait, the behaviors or methods can have implementations, which will be automatically inherited by "subclasses".
rust playground link
// ---  canine.rs ---

pub struct CanineState {
    is_sleeping: bool,
}
impl CanineState {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { is_sleeping: false }
    }
}

pub trait Canine {
    fn canine_mut(&mut self) -> &mut CanineState;

    // Predefined behavior all subclasses can use.    
    fn sleep(&mut self, b: bool) {
        println!("CanineState.is_sleeping = {b}");
        self.canine_mut().is_sleeping = b;
    }
}

// --- dog.rs ---

pub struct DogState {
    // Canine characteristics.
    canine_state: CanineState,
    
    // New dog characteristics.
    is_barking: bool,
}
impl DogState {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { canine_state: CanineState::new(), is_barking: false }
    }
    // Give subclasses a way to get the superclass' state.
    fn canine_mut(&mut self) -> &mut CanineState {
        &mut self.canine_state
    }
}

// Note the semantics here `Dog: Canine`. This declares that a Dog
// is a Canine.
pub trait Dog: Canine {
    // Unimplemented in virtual method.
    fn dog_mut(&mut self) -> &mut DogState;
    
    // Virtual behavior with implementation.
    fn bark(&mut self, b: bool) {
        println!("DogState.is_barking = {b}");
        self.dog_mut().is_barking = b;
    }
}

// --- pug.rs ---

// A Pug is a Dog which is a Canine.
//
pub struct Pug {
    dog_state: DogState,
    is_snorting: bool,
}
impl Pug {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { dog_state: DogState::new(), is_snorting: false }
    }
    // Pug has no subclasses, so we can implement its behaviors as 
    // struct funcs.
    pub fn snort(&mut self, b: bool) {
        println!("Pug.is_snorting = {b}");
        self.is_snorting = b
    }
}

// Implement the state accessor and automatically get all predefined 
// Dog behaviors.
//
impl Dog for Pug {
    // Only need to implement this.
    fn dog_mut(&mut self) -> &mut DogState {
        &mut self.dog_state
    }
}

// Implement the state accessor and automatically get all predefined 
// Canine behaviors.
//
impl Canine for Pug {
    // Only need to implement this. 
    fn canine_mut(&mut self) -> &mut CanineState {
        self.dog_state.canine_mut()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut pug = Pug::new();
    pug.snort(true);
    pug.bark(true);
    pug.bark(false);
    pug.snort(false);
    
    pug.sleep(true);
}

Pug.is_snorting = true
DogState.is_barking = true
DogState.is_barking = false
Pug.is_snorting = false
CanineState.is_sleeping = true

The modern trend in OO is to steer away from deep and/or complex hierarchies. In the past, many OO projects suffered from architectural flaws such as the fragile base class. "Uses" relationships are preferred unless there's a good reason for implementing hierarchies. The Decorator Pattern is a type of uses relationship, but it also could become unwieldy if overused. It's a good idea to keep hierarchical relationships shallow and straightforward.
To anyone who would assert that Rust is not OO, I would counter that the standard libraries and popular crates of Rust are, in fact, OO. Although state inheritance isn't supported directly by the language via structs, you see ample examples for behavior inheritance through traits. Just the act of implementing a custom iterator using the Iterator trait gives the implementor many new behaviors inherited from the interface. There are many other OO features built in to the language other than just behavior inheritance (polymorphism/dynamic dispatch).
Whether Rust is an "OO language" or not may come down to how one personally defines what an OO langauge is. Rust does not directly support state inheritance, but otherwise supports the primary features of an OO language. The GoF design patterns and other OO strategies can be easily implemented using Rust.
If you're new to Rust, don't be convinced to toss out all your aspirations of applying familiar OO concepts to your own projects, or give up on Rust altogether, just because someone early on tells you "Rust isn't OO". With that said, Rust is a unique, and somewhat difficult, language where one can't blindly try to make it fit their understandings on how OO could be applied. There are many Rust idiomatic ways of achieving features that one should become familiar with before committing to design decisions.

I would strongly advise against anyone attempting to apply OOP design patterns to Rust. This road ends in pain. Rust is not an OO language.

@cdhowie I emphatically disagree with you. Object Oriented programming is a tried and true approach to complex projects, and Rust does support it. And Rust IS an OO language as much as C++ is - both are multiparadigm.

I don't understand how the addresses OP's question...It's implementing a Trait for a type which is in a package which is not owned by them - in this case impl for  is disallowed

@Todd Rust Book says "Many competing definitions describe what OOP is, and by some of these definitions Rust is object-oriented, but by others it is not". It goes on to explain that inheritance can be bad, and how to implement some OOP patterns the Rust way...overall I'd disagree that it is an OO language, but open to interpretation I guess

@Todd Rust does not support value-type inheritance at all, one of the primary elements of the OO paradigm. If Rust is OO then it's missing one of the core features of OO.

@cdhowie is Gtk Object Oriented? Most definitely it is. It's primary language of implementation is C. If applying Rust to an OO design can end in pain, then Gtk would be extreme utter agony.

@Todd GObject kind of... is agony, in a lot of ways. Regardless, the best way to describe Gtk is that Gtk is built on GObject and C. GObject is what implements the OO paradigm on top of C. C is not OO.

@cdhowie Rust has all the features of what would be considered an OO language except state inheritance. Rust has vtables, it has virtual methods that can have implementation which can be inherited without the need to write additional code. Java has interfaces, which are a close analog for Rust traits. Rust has enough features to support multiparadigm development.

@Todd If you want to try OO dev in Rust you are absolutely welcome to. Eventually you are going to hit a wall where you are working so much against the grain that you paint yourself into a corner. There's plenty of history on both the Rust forums and SO of people trying to shoehorn OO into Rust. It just doesn't work well. That's my advice as someone who's been working in Rust for years now. Take it or leave it.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I have 7 yrs exp w/ Rust btw. Anyway, implementing a custom iterator for a type impl Iterator for MyType is very OO in nature. I would assert that doing so is "OO development". By doing so, your type inherits a lot of behaviors automatically. Just because state isn't transferred, doesn't make the process of implementing the iterator, non-OO.

@Todd, Thank you for the detailed response. It seems like the use case I am going for is not very idiomatically rust-y? Would this be an antipattern?

@bluesquare Rust, as with most OO languages, strongly enforces encapsulation and private data members (unless exposed intentionally). And what your question was describing sounded like you wanted a trait that could access the private data members of an external type. In languages like C++ or Java you can't make an external class a subclass of one of your own interfaces or classses without modifying the original code directly. Rust is a bit more flexible where you can add traits to external types.

@Todd yes but in many other languages (both C++ and Java) you can sub-class the original, and then have your custom sub-class have the statefulness you need, and have that also implement a 3rd "interface" if needed, but still store a reference/pointer/etc to the your new class in a collection of pointers to base class types.  Rust you can't do that, it's encapsulation.  Now there's reasons you shouldn't do that, but it's a difference of can versus can't.

@KevinAnderson right, you can't subclass a struct. Which is the rantionale for my post showing how to apply the decorator pattern to achieve extension goals for an external type. WRT aggregates/collections of a base type, you actually can do that in Rust. There are some things that are still unsupported however, like upcasting a trait to a supertrait (nightly has this to some degree).

@Todd Thanks.  I knew before that you could do that with a common trait but didn't know that Rust had Java-style (not just Java I know) multiple inheritance of Traits (cough interfaces).  I'm good with that, and I like your example you linked too, but that's news to me.  Apparently I skipped the Advanced Traits chapter in The Book.


But there's no statefulness!

simply is wrong, while you cannot implement this specific trait for just any type and crate1::Water is simply not one of the types you can implement it on.
You most certainly could implement it on this alternative Water:
pub struct Water {
    pub temperature: i32,
    pub state: String,
}

So the original statement has to be reworded as:
There is no statefulness that an external type doesn't expose.
Alternatively, you can always add arbitrary state by implementing Matter for a custom wrapper type instead of the external type directly:
struct MatterialWater {
    water: crate1::Water,
    temperature: i32,
    state: String,
}

